# Is it possible to have a facebook tab application without a tab?

Tags: facebook

A client wants to have a facebook page tab app, but they don't want the tab to be visible to the public. They're OK with the general public accessing the app if they obtain a link to it somehow, but don't want to advertise the app with a page tab icon at the top of their facebook page.

If I "Remove from favorites" on the page tab icon, the app itself becomes inaccessible. If I put the app in sandbox mode, only admins/testers can access it. All I really want to do is hide the icon itself but the leave the app up and running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have a page tab app which doesn't appear as a tab.

You/They should probably use a canvas app ('App on Facebook' in the settings, accessed via apps.facebook.com) for this purpose.

This also has the advantage of giving them more screen real estate to work with, and it can be kept 'anonymous' by just linking directly to it and not promoting it any other way